# How to Find files in Finder while I can read them in terminal on Docker

Tags: docker, terminal

I have a strange problem in terminal. I run "docker run" a certain project and then I have access to tons of folders and files that open and read them in terminal but there is no way that I can find them in the Finder!

And indeed I need to find some certain files in the Finder, or their address so I can email them to somebody!

please help me if you have any idea that how if there is any way that I can find those files in the Finder or just email them from Terminal while even though I have access to them I don't know their path/ on my computer!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should get the app EasyFind which will let you search specific folders or your whole disk for certain files, hidden or not. The app is very quick and does a thorough job or searching for a file. It is a free app available from the App Store.

Comment: that doesn't work, I guess the problem is that I only have access to those files when I run docker and my software under docker! I tried the EasyFind still finds nothing.